# 2 ways to change a javascript object's prototype, what's the difference between them?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype

I read this piece of code from stackoverflow, which indicates how to implement "inheritance" in javascript

```
var Base=function(){this.a='abc'};
var Sub = function () {};
Sub.prototype = new Base(); // note: this pattern is deprecated!
//Because we used 'new', the [[prototype]] property of Sub.prototype
//is now set to the object value of Base.prototype.
//The modern way to do this is with Object.create(), which was added in ECMAScript 5:
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
```

I wish to know, if

> Sub.prototype = new Base();

is deprecated, does the new way

> Object.create(Base.prototype);

introduce any internal difference of the object being created? Any internal property difference, behavior difference, so that I should use the new way, and try to convert old code to new code?

Thanks.

Comment: The big difference is that Object.create is not going to call the Base function. It's just going to set that function as the prototype and set up the prototype chains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho the modern way to do related things is [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and related keywords.

The two options you suggest produce different outcomes. See [classical inheritance with Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create()). You are missing both the call to the super constructor and the reassignment of `prototype.constructor` to the proper value (which is also missing in the other case).

When doing inheritance with `Object.create` as described in the link, one difference compared to assigning `new Base()` is where the properties can be found:

```js
function Base() { this.baseProp = "baseProp"; }
function Sub() { this.subProp = "subProp"; }

Sub.prototype = new Base();
Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;

let obj = new Sub();
console.log("obj.baseProp: " + obj.baseProp);
console.log("Has baseProp on itself: " + obj.hasOwnProperty("baseProp"));
```

```js
function Base() { this.baseProp = "baseProp"; }
function Sub() {
  Base.call(this);
  this.subProp = "subProp";
}

//Note that here Base.prototype doesnt even have anything interesting
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;

let obj = new Sub();
console.log("obj.baseProp: " + obj.baseProp);
console.log("Has baseProp on itself: " + obj.hasOwnProperty("baseProp"));
```

Also note that `Object.create` still pushes an extra indirection into the prototype chain (where with the other method the object containing the properties of `Base` would be). However, the extra step is not "wrong" but can be seen as splitting of prototype properties of `Sub` and prototype properties inherited (e.g. if you wanted to add something to `Sub.prototype`, you'd have a hard time doing so without this indirection, as you would accidentally add to `Base.prototype` aswell)

```js
function Base() { this.baseProp = "baseProp"; }
Base.prototype.someFunction = () => void 0;
function Sub() {
  Base.call(this);
  this.subProp = "subProp";
}

//Now this is important, the prototype contains something
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;

let obj = new Sub();
console.log("First level link has function: " + obj.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("someFunction"));
console.log("Second level link has function: " + obj.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("someFunction"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can point is that when you use `new` then the prototype of `Sub` is an **instance** of `Base`. This means that **all properties** will be available on the sub class (not only the prototype methods).

So in your example `Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);` inherits nothing. While `Sub.prototype = new Base()` inherits the `a` property